# Indefinite loop in a coroutine vs. re-scheduling a coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, asynchronous, async-await

I recently started working with asyncio and coroutines. I have a coroutine that runs every 0.25 seconds to print "running ..." on screen indefinitely. When the script receives a SIGTERM or SIGINT it will exit gracefully.

I figured out that there are two ways to do that.

- Method A: Run a `while True:` loop in the coroutine and have a helper-coroutine to stop the loop after my main coroutine finished running (leaves "pending" status).
- Method B: Have the coroutine re-schedule itself.

While method A just calls the couroutine *once*, method 2 does not need a helper-coroutine to close the loop gracefully. **Is there a suggested way on doing this? Are there any up or downsides to one or the other?**

#### Method A

```
import asyncio
import signal


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    asyncio.async(my_coroutine_a())

    for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        loop.add_signal_handler(sig, ask_exit)

    loop.run_forever()
    print("Closing event loop")
    loop.close()


@asyncio.coroutine
def my_coroutine_a():
    print("Coroutine started")
    while True:
        try:
            print("running ...")
            # print(channel_layer.receive(["my_channel"]))
            yield from asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("stopping ...")
            raise


@asyncio.coroutine
def exit_coro():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.stop()
    print("Coroutine stopped")


def ask_exit():
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()
    asyncio.async(exit_coro())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Method B

```
import asyncio
import signal


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    asyncio.async(my_coroutine_b())

    for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        loop.add_signal_handler(sig, ask_exit)

    print("Coroutine started")
    loop.run_forever()
    print("Coroutine stopped")
    print("Closing event loop")
    loop.close()


@asyncio.coroutine
def my_coroutine_b():
    try:
        print("running ...")
        # print(channel_layer.receive(["my_channel"]))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.25)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("stopping ...")
        asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
        raise

    asyncio.async(my_coroutine_b())


def ask_exit():
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Output Method A & B

```
Coroutine started
running ...
running ...
running ...
running ...
running ...
running ...
running ...
stopping ...
Coroutine stopped
Closing event loop

Process finished with exit code 0
```